# Plot flot points with no data

Tags: javascript, flot

I was wondering, is there an easy way to plot points that have no data?  For example, my dataset could have

> [["2013-11-01", 1],["2013-11-03", 1],["2013-11-04", 1],["2013-11-05",
>   1]]

I would like for flot to plot 2013-11-02 as 0. Otherwise, flot skips this and draws a line from 11-01 to 11-03.  I'm trying to avoid this on the backend, so any solution using the library would be great.

Comment: Loop through the days of your date range, and insert the 0 values as needed?

Answer (score 2):

Either set those data points to 0 or null (it does different things).

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format):

> If a null is specified as a point or if one of the coordinates is null
>   or couldn't be converted to a number, the point is ignored when
>   drawing. As a special case, a null value for lines is interpreted as a
>   line segment end, i.e. the points before and after the null value are
>   not connected.

So if you set it to null, you'll get your lines skipping that X-axis point.  If you set it to 0, your line will drop to zero until the next X-axis value.